# Synonym for "a lot" where each contributes only a little

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a professional-context appropriate synonym for the word "a lot", but with the additional expression of "each contributes only a little"

For example,

> To fill up that vat you'd need a crapload of tennis balls.

Here "crapload" implies that each individual tennis ball is actually worthless on it's own.  Where the vat is big, "crapload" serves to color the sentence.

Unfortunately "crapload" is unprofessional.  "A lot" is just colorless.  Suggestions?

Comment: I think you're mistaken in your assumption that the word *crapload* itself implies numerous "low-value" or otherwise "insignificant" elements. More common equivalents in British English are *shitload* and (euphemised, but still colloquial) *shedload*, but I'm sure AmE is the same - the elements are only "small" by implication because even a very large number of them will only fill a vat (not, say, a swimming pool). If you have a *crapload / shitload / shedload* of work to do, that certainly doesn't imply "a large number of very small tasks" - it just means **a lot of work in total**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

> To fill up that vat you'd need ***a great many*** tennis balls.
>
> To fill up that vat you'd need ***countless*** tennis balls.

The phrase *a great many* is often used to convey the idea of *an awful lot*; with a great many hits on Google books ([well over a million](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20great%20many%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1950,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22a%20great%20many%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&sa=X&ei=w7keUKziE4KFyQGd-YDQBQ&ved=0CC0QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1950,cd_max:12/31/2000&tbm=bks&fp=1&biw=1170&bih=834&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=LLseULnTB4jBygHn_QE), in fact).

***[Countless](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/countless)*** doesn't really mean *uncountable*, but suggests that it might take a truckload of time to count all the tennis balls.

Comment: Agreed - in OP's context, *a great many* would be normal phrasing, but most people would find *plethora* or *myriad* somewhat "flowery", to say the least.

Answer (score 8):

*[Plethora](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plethora#Noun)* ("An excessive amount or number; an abundance") and  *[myriad](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myriad#Noun)* ("A countless number or multitude (of specified things)" or (now historical) "Ten thousand") are used in such contexts; or you can use both: "To fill up that plethoric vat you'd need a myriad of tennis balls." Note, *[plethoric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plethoric)* does not necessarily mean many, but instead "overabundant or rife", "excessive", or "ruddy in complexion", depending on what or who you apply it to.  You could also say *an army* of tennis balls or a *whole host*.

Comment: +1 for myriad; not so sure about plethora since I don't think he means to imply a surfeit.

Comment: ... and I'm used to seeing _plethora_ used in the context of variety. +1 for _myriad_ :)

Answer (score 1):

> "To fill up that vat you'd need *a crapload* of tennis balls."

Depending on the level of professionalism you are looking for:

> "To fill up that vat you'd need a(n) *[zillion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zillion)/[gazillion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gazillion)/[myriad](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myriad)/innumerable number/staggering number/countless number* of tennis balls."

For such situations, a [thesaurus is usually very handy](http://thesaurus.com/browse/innumerable).

Comment: A variant on this one can be rather amusing in everyday conversation, if you use "billions and billions," and utter it with your best Carl Sagan impression.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it doesn't have to be limited to the whole "*tennis balls and vat*" example above.

If so, I'd suggest: **a barrage of**

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/barrage) defines this word as:

```
an overwhelming and continuous delivery of something
```

so it fits in business/ professional settings.