# "There is a number of" versus "There are a number of"

Tags: grammatical-number

As a native speaker, this sounds correct:

> There are a number of cows in that field.

whilst this sounds totally wrong:

> There is a number of cows in the field.

But arguably the second form might be technically correct, because "a" indicates "a number" is singular.

Some examples support this hypothesis: "There is a collection of cows in that field."

Whilst others contradict it: "There are a lot of cows in that field."

Can you confirm which is correct, and is there a good justification which can be generalised to other situations?

Comment: Related question, [Is the sentence “There is a large number of labourers who want to migrate to Japan for work.” correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/is-the-sentence-there-is-a-large-number-of-labourers-who-want-to-migrate-to-jap). It was marked as duplicate and you can click on the duplicate in the link.

Comment: Thank you.  I now see that there are a [barrage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77213/synonym-for-a-lot-where-each-contributes-only-a-little) of questions addressing this concern already.

Comment: Yes, that means the question is popular. It would be better to use the search before posting a question. :-)